# Factor analysis of a function with binary output

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I have a data set and I am interested in determining which factors of this data set contribute most to the output. The data set varies by multiple factors $X_1$, $X_2$, .... $X_n$, and the function produces an outcome $F$($X_1$,$X_2$,...$X_n$)=$1$ or $0$. $X_1$ and the other variables are typically limited to taking on  1-5 different values. However, these values are not numeric, they can sometimes be strings representing a location or something else. I am looking for a way to quantify which of the variables are most important in determining the outcome of the function.

I have tried assigning the values that each of the random factors $X_1$, $X_2$, .... $X_n$ can take to vectors, but a possible problem is the dimension of each random factor may differ. Is there anyway to determine the importance of these variables on the general function?

(by importance I mean something in the way of principal component analysis or sensitivity of the function to those factors)

Comment: Is there something about how $F$ behaves that causes you to avoid logistic regression?  Are you truly referring to "factor analysis" as described at [tag:factor-analysis]?  Your question doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: Maybe not, that may work! I am expecting the data to be very weakly correlated however. What do you think is the best way to represent my variables? For example, $X_1$ can be three different values, while $X_2$ can take on 5 different values. Should they be treated as vectors, and then there will be an equally sized vector corresponding to its weights? How can i fit these different sized variables into one logistic model? Thank you for your comment

Comment: That comment hides a lot of big questions.  Have you considered consulting a textbook on multiple regression?  That might be the quickest and easiest way to discover what you need to know and to get good information about it.